# Using Core Audio API to change volume of rear channels

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a background application that allows me to easily change volumes of the rear channels

I've looked into the [Core Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and although I managed to change the balance/volume of the front speakers, the API seemingly had no access to the rear channels or any other surround channel. It only counted 2 channels for my audio device.

Is it in any way possible, using any API, to control the rear channel's volume?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Thanks, FMOD looks like what I need, although it's a bit overwhelming. :P What would I need to do, to change the volume of a specified channel. I believe I need this function:

```
FMOD.RESULT result = channel.setVolume(1.0f);
```

But then I need to find a way to specify the channel...

Also, to be clear: I need to change the volume of any running application, say Winamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best chose for working with audio file is "[Fmod.dll](http://www.fmod.org/)".this have a lot of Privilege to work with audio file.

> This is an audio content creation tool for games, with a focus on a
>   ‘Pro Audio’ approach. It has an entirely new interface that will be
>   more familiar to those using professional Digital Audio Workstations
>   than existing game audio tools and is loaded with new features.

I already use this,this is very powerful component and easy to use.